# Displaying an image until a certain date using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to display an announcement on website. I hope it can automatically stop showing on, say Feb 1st 2014. Anybody knows how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in page_load of your page:

```
yourAnnouncementControl.Visible = (DateTime.Now < DateTime.Parse("2014/02/01"));
```

Be careful about `DateTime` format in parse method.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX:

```
<img id="ann" src="../img/banner.jpg" alt="ann" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
```

Code behind:

```
if(DateTime.Now< new DateTime(2014,2,1))
   ann.Visible= true;
```